# Using scipy from C++ via pybind11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, scipy, pybind11

I would like to have the possibility to use python modules like *numpy*, *scipy*, etc. from C++. The following code tries to call *scipy.optimize.curve_fit* to fit a parabolic function. A problem occures when calling *curve_fit*. Here, an exception is thrown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>           // mandatory for myPyObject.cast<std::vector<T>>()
#include <pybind11/functional.h>    // mandatory for py::cast( std::function )

namespace py = pybind11;

int main()
{
    try {
        py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

        py::module np = py::module::import("numpy");
        py::object random = np.attr("random");

        py::module scipy = py::module::import("scipy.optimize");

        // create some data for fitting
        std::vector<double> xValues(11, 0);
        std::vector<double> yValues(11, 0);
        for (int i = -5; i < 6; ++i) {
            xValues[i + 5] = i;
            yValues[i + 5] = i*i;
        }

        // cast it to numpy arrays
        py::array_t<double> pyXValues = py::cast(xValues);
        py::array_t<double> pyYValues = py::cast(yValues);

        // add some noise to the yValues using numpy -> Works!
        py::array_t<double> pyYValuesNoise = np.attr("add")(pyYValues, random.attr("randn")(11));

        // create a function f_a(x) = a*x^2
        std::function<std::vector<double>(std::vector<double>, double)> squared = [](std::vector<double> x, double a) {
            std::vector<double> retvals(x);
            std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), retvals.begin(), [a](double val) { return a*val*val; });
            return retvals;
        };

        // cast it to a python function
        py::function pySquared = py::cast(squared);     

        // get scipy.optimize.curve_fit
        py::function curve_fit = scipy.attr("curve_fit");

        // call curve_fit -> throws exception
        /* py::object = */ curve_fit(pySquared, pyXValues, pyYValues);

    }
    catch (std::exception error) {
        std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The exception gives the information:

> ValueError: no signature found for builtin < built-in method  of PyCapsule object at 0x00000204FFE9C630>
>
> At:
>     D:\Programs\python36_6_x64\Lib\inspect.py(2090): _signature_from_builtin
>     D:\Programs\python36_6_x64\Lib\inspect.py(2266): _signature_from_callable
>     D:\Programs\python36_6_x64\Lib\inspect.py(2802): from_callable
>     D:\Programs\python36_6_x64\Lib\inspect.py(3052): signature
>     D:\Programs\python36_6_x64\lib\site-packages\scipy_lib_util.py(290): getargspec_no_self
>    D:\Programs\python36_6_x64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py(685): curve_fit

How do I call curve_fit from C++ correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you. But I do think that you could make your question even clear by removing the `stdafx.h` library and removing the `try`-`except` construction.

Comment: Removed the stdafx.h, but whats the reason to remove the `try`-`except`?

Comment: Of course there is no strong argument, but it does not make your question clearer (not really less clear either) so then I would always omit it on this platform

Comment: I understand why this doesn't work, `curve_fit` is a higher order function, which automatically initializes variable(s) matching the signature of the trailing arguments for the objective function. If you really want this, you could execute a few python lines, where the objective function is a python function, perhaps calling a c++ function.

Comment: @JensMunk So it is not possible to call a function taking a function as argument via pybind directly?

Comment: @Dragoner. It is possible, but not in general. I think what goes wrong is that `curve_fit` is allocating a variable for optimization based on the types of the trailing arguments. Could you try defining a `squared` in python and import that function.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Jens Munk's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762140/using-scipy-from-c-via-pybind11#comment90576897_51762140) I created a Python module "MyPythonModule" that contains the file "MyFunctionality.py", with the function

```
def python_square_function(x, a):
    return a*x**2
```

I added the path to this module to the environment variable PYTHONPATH. The C++ code was changed to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>    // for myPyObject.cast<std::vector<T>>()

namespace py = pybind11;

int main()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    py::module np = py::module::import("numpy");
    py::object random = np.attr("random");
    py::module scipy = py::module::import("scipy.optimize");

    // Load created module containing f_a(x) = a*x^2
    py::module myModule = py::module::import("MyPythonModule.MyFunctionality");

    // Create some data for fitting
    std::vector<double> xValues(11, 0);
    std::vector<double> yValues(11, 0);
    for (int i = -5; i < 6; ++i) {
        xValues[i + 5] = i;
        yValues[i + 5] = i*i;
    }

    // Cast data to numpy arrays
    py::array_t<double> pyXValues = py::cast(xValues);
    py::array_t<double> pyYValues = py::cast(yValues);

    // Add some noise to the yValues using numpy
    py::array_t<double> pyYValuesNoise = np.attr("add")(pyYValues, random.attr("randn")(11));

    // Get the function f_a(x) = a*x^2 we want to fit
    py::function pySquareFunction = myModule.attr("python_square_function");

    // Load scipy.optimize.curve_fit
    py::function curve_fit = scipy.attr("curve_fit");

    // Call curve_fit
    py::object retVals = curve_fit(pySquareFunction, pyXValues, pyYValuesNoise);

    // The return value contains the optimal values and the covariance matrix.
    // Get the optimal values
    py::object optVals = retVals.attr("__getitem__")(0);

    // Cast return value back to std::vector and show the result
    std::vector<double> retValsStd = optVals.cast<std::vector<double>>();
    std::cout << "Fitted parameter a = " << retValsStd[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code leads to the expected behavior: the fitted parameter `a = 0.978144`.

Unfortunately, this is still a workaround, that uses a bit of external Python code. It would be great to be able define everything inside the C++ source.